# electron-build failed on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron application and I failed to run `electron-builder` in Ubuntu. The electron builder version I am using is `"electron-builder": "^19.10.0"`.

I got below error. It looks like a `xorriso` issue but I have updated `xorriso` to 1.4.2. What else can cause this error?

```
GNU xorriso 1.4.4 : RockRidge filesystem manipulator, libburnia project.

xorriso : WARNING : -volid text does not comply to ISO 9660 / ECMA 119 rules
libburn : SORRY : Neither stdio-path nor its directory exist
xorriso : FAILURE : Cannot acquire drive '/home/developer/jenkins/dist/@southbanksoftware/dbkoda-0.6.0-x86_64.AppImage'
xorriso : aborting : -abort_on 'FAILURE' encountered 'FAILURE'

GNU xorriso 1.4.4 : RockRidge filesystem manipulator, libburnia project.

xorriso : WARNING : -volid text does not comply to ISO 9660 / ECMA 119 rules
libburn : SORRY : Neither stdio-path nor its directory exist
xorriso : FAILURE : Cannot acquire drive '/home/developer/jenkins/dist/@southbanksoftware/dbkoda-0.6.0-x86_64.AppImage'
xorriso : aborting : -abort_on 'FAILURE' encountered 'FAILURE'

    at /home/developer/jenkins/agent/node_modules/electron-builder-util/src/util.ts:64:16
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:217:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:513:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the immediate problem is that xorriso cannot create the result file

```
/home/developer/jenkins/dist/@southbanksoftware/dbkoda-0.6.0-x86_64.AppImage
```

because the directory

```
/home/developer/jenkins/dist/@southbanksoftware
```

does not exist.

Why the directory was not prepared and whether its name is the
appropriate one is out of my knowledge. I would assume that this in
the responsibility of electron-builder.

Have a nice day :)

Thomas